# Script src vs script in page code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 7000 line js script. What is better putting the script in page like `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>` or putting like `<script>my script blah blah blah</script>`

Comment: How many times will the user visit this page? more than once?

Comment: yes, it's one of the main pages

Comment: Then you'll want to load it as an external script with proper caching headers so that the user only has to download it once.

Comment: Will that work on mobile?

Comment: Exactly what @KevinB said. You might want to compress the script for shorter load times as well.

Comment: Yes, it will work on mobile browsers. (Although some of the browsers on my phone prompt to clear the cache on exit, and obviously if users of those browsers say "yes" to that prompt then the JS file would have to be downloaded again next time.)

Comment: So you are asking whether you should put 7000 lines of code into a document with other unrelated code/markup instead of having them in a standalone file?

Comment: so <script src="myscripts.js"></script> wins?

Comment: 99.99% of the time yes

Comment: I'd say go for the external file, but if the script is only used on one page, and that page is static and cached as well, it doesn't really matter, but it's still good practice to seperate javascript from HTML, and when it's 7000 lines it sounds like a lot of clutter in a HTML file!

Comment: Almost always, the included script file wins.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always more efficient to use external js files with proper caching headers so that the client only has to download it once rather than every time they visit/reload the page.

More efficient in multiple ways:

- Faster overall load times
- Easier to work on the code (less hours spent maintaining)
- Easier to diagnose code problems (less hours spent maintaining)
- Easier to minify the code (less hours spent maintaining)

Comment: Can you please explain me what you mean when you said "proper caching headers" ?

Answer (score 0):

If this forms a library of functions that are used throughout the site, you are better off with it being an referenced script tag. If it is specific to the page, leave it on the page.

With it being referenced, you get the benefit of the server caching the included page, and the browser not pulling it down multiple times if nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

A good web programming practice is to separate your Model(HTML), View(CSS) and Controller(JS), so called front end MVC.

You might also what to check out [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) for more detailed explanation on why should you keep your JS separate from your Models.

Comment: The three languages isn't really the same as a MVC setup, but still good point.

Comment: @adeneo well buzz words fly around these days so it's hard to be verbally precise even if you know what's going on. For sure this is very different idea with traditional server side concept of MVC. Indeed I probably should have avoided using this word to reduce confusion.